# If a DB field has a certain value show on top of results

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I know I can achieve that by using the "when" but I'm not really sure how to in codeigniter :(

Will appreciate any help.

```
  $this->db->order_by("time_out = yes","asc"); // something like this

  $this->db->where('status','Pending');
  $this->db->or_where('status','Kitchen');

  $sql = $this->db->get('pedidos');
```

Answer (score 0):

What other values do you have for time_out? why not just sort by time_out?

you can also select an if statement:

```
SELECT *, IF(time_out='yes',1,0) as timeOutSort ......
```

then do

```
$this->db->order_by("timeOutSort","DESC");
```